# Laravel Oracle11gへの接続

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravelをインストール後

- yajra/laravel-oci8を導入
- php.iniを編集
  `extension=php_oci8_11g.dll ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client`を追記
- config\database.phpの設定

以上を行い、マイグレーション実行を行ったところ

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   Unsupported driver [oracle]

となり、接続ができませんでした。

⇒config/app.php の記載漏れが原因でした。
記載を行い再度マイグレーション実行を行ったところ

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>   Call to undefined function Yajra\Pdo\oci_connect()

となり、接続ができませんでした。

なにか分かる方はおらっしゃいますでしょうか？
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: laravel-oci8が正しく読み込まれていないように思うのですが、`config/app.php` にServiceProviderの記載はされましたか？

Comment: unarist様　config/app.phpの記載が漏れておりました。助言ありがとうございます。記載を入れたところ以下のエラーとなりました。 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
 Call to undefined function Yajra\Pdo\oci_connect()

Answer (score 1):

> Call to undefined function Yajra\Pdo\oci_connect()

[laravel-oci8のリポジトリでも多数同様のエラーが報告されています](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8/search?q=oci_connect&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93)が、要するに `php_oci8_11g.dll` が正しく読み込めていません。具体的には、

- `php_oci8_11g.dll` が存在しない
- Oracleのクライアントライブラリ（Oracle Instant Clientなど）がインストールされていない
  参考： [Windows 環境の PHP から Oracle へ接続する - Qiita](http://qiita.com/nanasess/items/efa7c027838509a44586)
- 同ライブラリにPATHが通っていない

等がよくある原因のようです。